# How to create a multi-indexed DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I need to create a multi-indexed table of data using DataFrames in Python.

Basically, I want the left index to be a timestamp (it's in date-time), and the following data to be in columns indexed by date. [I.e. I have a timestamp and two columns of data stored in this DataFrame, say DF0.]
[image: 1]

Say each of the DataFrames (i.e. DF0) has an ID attached to it. That would be the secondary index overhanging above the column titles.

[This is the table after merging two DataFrames, say DF0 and DF1.]
[image: 2] This is the ideal output but it needs a secondary index that I would be able to assign, we can say 5 and 6 for this example.

[The ideal output is this picture.]
[image: 3]

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: hi @rainbownlegend21. Post a [mcve] with text instead of images to maximize the chances people can reproduce your code and help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```py
pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['ID1','ID2'], axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Do you know how I could do the same thing but if there was more than just 2 dataframes? Let's say a list of like 10 dataframes? I would have a list of the IDs to match with the DataFrames, would the best way be through a for loop of a sort?